# How to produce replacement for several substrings with single regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a source string containing some of the following substrings:

- "first"
- "second"

It is necessary to replace them correspondingly to

- "third"
- "forth"

I do that the following way

```
var output = input;

var re1 = /first/;
var re2 = /second/;

output = output.replace(re1, "third")
output = output.replace(re2, "forth")
```

The question is how to do that with single regular expression?

Comment: Why do you want to use only one regular expression ?

Comment: `/first/` will only find the first `first` unless it's global: `/first/g`

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote this question.

Comment: @dystroy I would like to know if it is possible and if it is then how to do that because regex looks like short way to do that kind of job.

Comment: The problem is that the answers you'll see are worsening your code : they add duplication and don't improve performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something like this; using an anonymous function:

```
var input = "This is the first... no second time that I tell you this!";
var result = input.replace(/first|second/g, function(m) {
    switch(m)
    {
    case "first":
      return "third";
    case "second":
      return "forth";
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unknown008/pc57E/2/)

The variable `m` will contain the match, passed to a `switch` where you can add more replacements if you need.

Comment: It is less concise than @Pointy answer, but it shows how to add several other cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a function passed to `.replace()`:

```
output = output.replace(/first|second/g, function(word) {
  return word === "first" ? "third" : "fourth";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible unless you pass a function as the second argument.

```
var a =function(a){if(a=="first"){ a="third" }else{ a="forth"} return a}
output = output.replace(/first|second/g, a);
```

Then you may as well just write a one liner.

```
output = output.replace(/first/g, "third").replace(/second/g, "forth");
```

Comment: It works well, but it doesn't answer the question: "how to do that with [a] single regular expression?"

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Now it answers.